# Is it possible to format a disk as ext4 on big sur using some brew package?

Tags: homebrew, formatting, ext4

I see a lot of questions asking how to mount and access ext4 file systems, which can be solved with the brew packages: `macFUSE, ext4FUSE`.

#### The Question:

Is there a way to format an external disk to ext4? I can't find any brew packages, so am I just going to have to get a linux vm?

Comment: I  would assume you could boot to a live version of Ubuntu and format from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In macOS, all your internal and external drives are just `/dev/diskX` files where the X is the disk number.

```
diskutil list
```

To created a filesystem on an external disk, you will need to partition it. With free space on the disk, you can do so with this command:

```
gpt add -t 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 diskX
```

Once partitioned, you format the partition.

```
brew install e2fsprogs
`brew --prefix e2fsprogs`/sbin/mkfs.ext4 /dev/diskXs1
mke2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Creating filesystem with 97632 1k blocks and 24384 inodes
...
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

Then mount with the `macFuse` ext4 command.

It is also interesting they can still support fuse, as Apple [discontinued kernel extensions](https://developer.apple.com/support/kernel-extensions/) in Big Sur.

This makes all fuse filesystem look like network shares.

Comment: So how do you format the partition as ext4?

Comment: @Gilby Added how to format to the answer. Updated and thanks.

Comment: @JamesRisner Way before this answer I ended up installing parallels with a centos vm and just got it over with. 

However I tried your steps after formatting the disk to fat32 but got: 

`gpt add /dev/disk2s1: error: no primary GPT header; run create or recover`

I googled how to fix this and after several attempts nothing worked. 

Thank you very much though I'll use this in the future.